# How to ask two turtles of the same breed to do something if they share the same patch on Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

i am trying to make a code that should ask two turtles of the same breed where one of them would have the black color , if they share the same patch , and to [ do something ] if they do .

```
ask breed-here with color black [ do something]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I hope this gets you on the right path. Lets say your breed is called 'humans':

```
ask humans with [color = black]
[ if any? other humans-on patch-here
  [ ; do something
  ]
]
```

So this looks at every turtle of the breed 'humans' that is coloured black, that turtle looks on the patch they are standing (`patch-here`) to see if there's at least one other human of any colour.

Comment: i will try it and see the results